# Why was a 10 year old question/ answer suddenly marked as low quality?

Tags: discussion

This came up in the review queue.  [image]

What would cause it to pop after all this time?

Comment: I'm curious about this too now, thanks for bringing it up.   This site was moderated very differently in its first year than it is today.   Many of the questions and answers would be low quality or off-topic by today's standards.   From the 2011-2012 time period there are lots of questions asking for software recommendations and many very short answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, this happens when a user flagged that post as Not An Answer. Both the Very Low Quality and Not An Answer flags put an answer in the Low Quality Posts review queue (if it didn't have one before) and the Very Low Quality flag is not available on posts older than 7 days.

Another possibility would be that this is a [review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/review-audits/info) but they're not enabled on Webmasters Stack Exchange.

This might be a real bug in the system, or not; anyway, I now remember I asked about a similar case a couple of months ago on Meta Stack Exchange:
[Answer in Low Quality Posts review queue without flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351416/295232) but no response so far.

Comment: I don't see anything in the timeline for that answer that indicates that it was flagged.  The only entries are that it was created, that it entered the review queue, and that the review was completed.   The "show flag history" for it in the moderator options in greyed out which I think indicates that it has never been flagged.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for checking. That is *really* surprising. There is nothing here either? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/12238/show-flags

Comment: The only thing there is the an entry for the post creation with the type "Initial Body."

Comment: My theory is that the automated checks for low quality that are typically run on new posts are sometimes run against old posts.    I'm not sure of the mechanics of how that would work though.  If staff is doing that they have to have set it up in a way to have them trickle in and not flood the queues.

Comment: Wait, now I realize I posted [a bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351416/295232) a couple of months ago...

Comment: I have a knack for finding this sort of stuff ;o)